# Is a chuffing sound from a 1999 Saab 9-3 sign of an exhaust leak?

Tags: exhaust, leak, saab, gasket

I hear this sound when running alongside curbs or concrete walls with RPMs below 2000.  I suspect it's a leaking exhaust manifold gasket, and intend to replace this in the near future.  When I try to locate the source of the sound with the hood open and the engine idling, I cannot pinpoint any leak, possibly because of all the other noises under the hood.

Could this sound be other than a leaking exhaust manifold gasket?

Comment: To pinpoint the sound, they sell stethoscopes for automotive use.  point it around and see where the sound is the loudest.

Comment: here's a link to the stethoscope            https://www.google.com/search?q=automotive+stethoscope&oq=automotive+steth&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.7873j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=automotive+stethoscope&tbm=shop

Comment: It could well be a leaking exhaust, or gasket.  Since the engine isn't under load when idling, there may not be sufficient exhaust pressure to cause the 'chuffing' noise when listening with the hood up.

Answer (score 1):

I would put money on this being the brakes chuffing on the rotors, or something related with the wheel going around. The easiest way to test this theory is to jack the car up and spin the wheel. Should exhibit the same type of noise.

Comment: Never considered brakes, but easy enough to check.  Will do ASAP and report back.